# converted .py to exe, but exe won't open

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, exe, cx-freeze

I converted my .py file using cx_Freeze successfully. No errors in command prompt or anything. But for some reason, when I try and open the exe file, nothing happens. Note that I have used tkinter and matplotlib in my .py file.

Here's my code for setup.py:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

import os
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Program Files\\Anaconda3\\tcl\\tcl8.6"
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Program Files\\Anaconda3\\tcl\\tk8.6"

setup (name = 'CODAQ Beta', version = '0.1', description = 'Aerosol Data Visualization Environment', executables = [Executable("CODAQ.py")])
```

And here's what I enter into command prompt:

`C:\Users\louisa\Desktop> python setup.py build`

Everything seems right, is it something to with tkinter or matplotlib? Any tips on how to get this working?

Comment: Does it work without those libraries? Does it only work with one or the other? Does the console output anything when you run the .exe from the command line?

Comment: did you run it console (command prompt) to see any error message ?

Comment: never tried opening it via command line, but when I do, i get an import error: `Import Error: cannot import name '_methods'`

Comment: ok so i created a separate py file with the just the tkinter module imported, tried to convert it to an exe and ran into a similar problem, this time i get the error: `import _tkinter # If this fails your python may not be configured for Tk ImportError:DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`